# Get the address of a ctypes object

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a buffer like:

```
bufstr = ctypes.create_string_buffer("Test", 32)
```

How I obtain the address of that buffer? i.e. the one displayed if I do:

```
print bufstr
```

like:

```
<ctypes.c_char_Array_32 object at 0x042ACAD0>
```

I know I can pass it with byref(), for example; but what if I just want to get that address (aside from slicing that string!)?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Why do you want the address?

Comment: @Apalala: have to pass it to an embedded DLL that need to access that buffer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use ctypes.[addressof](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof).

```
ctypes.addressof(bufstr)
```

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry, didn't noticed you reply before)

Comment: Now another thing. This works OK for a buffer string created with ctypes.create_string_buffer. But, what if I have to pass a simple long? addressof() don't work with a ctypes.c_long (give a TypeError).

Comment: Just tried it myself in the interpreter to be sure, it works just fine with `ctypes.c_long`.

Comment: Whoops! You are right. I was just being stupid. After assigning my var to ctypes.c_long, I had a myvar = 3, witch of course reassinged a Python Int.

Answer (score 5):

I believe:

```
ctypes.addressof(bufstr)
```

should do it. Note that the address mentioned in toString is for the Python object, not the C memory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the address given in `bufstr.__str__()` isn't the same value as `addressof(buf_str)`, that had me confused.